# Draggable legends on leaflet maps

Tags: leaflet, cartography

Is there a way to make a leaflet map's legend draggable? Like a library, or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a piece of code from this Leaflet example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html

```
    var legend = L.control({ position: 'bottomright' });

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i];
            to = grades[i + 1];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');

        var draggable = new L.Draggable(div);
        draggable.enable()

        return div;
    };
```

I added in these two lines of code to make the legend moveable.

```
var draggable = new L.Draggable(div);
draggable.enable()
```

Using Leaflet's Draggable class: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#draggable